# How can I change colors of list component with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have tried all kinds of solutions but nothing works. Does someone know how I can change color of background, selected item, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe help shows you how to [Customize the List component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f41.html). You can modify `Up_Skin` or `Over_Skin` in the Cell Renderer skins.

Comment: What I need is a good example! Using renderer the Up_Skin and Over_skin doesn't work. They must be upSkin and overSkin. I need to know all the "skin" possibilities where can I find a list of them.

Comment: Found a good example and now everything else is working but how can I change the color of the list background or is it even possible? And now I don't know how to change colors of a scrollBar because it doesn't use rendered skins. I'm so stupid that I find no help from Adope's help.